# Open and close a sibling div when trigger is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to allow users to click on the `[+]` trigger and have it's sibling div open and close to display that topic's information.

Why can't this find the sibling?

```
$('.moreInfo').hide();
$('a.triggerButton').click(function(){
  var $this = $('a.triggerButton');
  $this.find().siblings('.moreInfo').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

I made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JFw9g/8/). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because firstly you should address `this` anchor element, and secondly get rid of useless `.find()`:

```
$("a.triggerButton").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".moreInfo").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/JFw9g/9/